# Strange output when using PrintWriter

Tags: java, printing, writefile

So, I just started using Java for coding today and I am trying to print a String and an Integer to a text file. Here is my shortened code. First I get a user input with the help of a Scanner sc. 
This user input is my name string  which is added to an array list. Then I force another User Input (int) which equals the coinValue. Now I want to print those values to a text file.

```
        String name;
        name = sc.next();
        names.add(name);
        if (names.add(name) == true){
            // some System.out methods here
        }
        int coinValue = sc.nextInt();
        coins.add(coinValue);
        if (coins.add(coinValue) == true) {
            // some System.out. methods here

            PrintWriter printout = new PrintWriter("info.txt");
            printout.print(name);
            printout.print("," + coinValue);
            printout.println("---------------");
            printout.close();

        }
```

So if I use e.g. String name = "test"; and int coinValue = "100000" it prints:

> ¨Ìsrjava.util.ArrayListxÅ“ô«aùIsizexpwttestq~xsq~wsrjava.lang.Integer‚†§˜Åá8Ivaluexrjava.lang.NumberÜ¨ïî‡ãxpÜ†x

I tried to fix for like an hour and went throgh like 200 stackoverflow questions but I cannot seem to get it working for this particular problem.

Comment: Is that the java error exactly?  I don't think I've ever seen it printed like that

Comment: looks like you have trouble with your encoding and the output is definitively not from the code you posted. this produces for me "test,10000---------------"

Comment: why are you calling .add twice on your arraylists? also i would suggest using nextLine() when grabbing data from the user, then when you ask for the coin, just call Integer.parseInt() on the returned string from the user

Comment: I do not get a java error. This is what gets printed into the info.txt when the project is exported and runned as a .jar

Comment: Does it work running from a .class file?  What if you specify the full filepath to be written to?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't post complete code?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I could have posted the complete code but I felt like it would be akward to spam you helping people with a wall of text. :(

Comment: @phflack running from a .class file does work when specifiying the full filepath somehow, does not work as  a .jar though..

Comment: Actually, posting the complete code means less effort for us to run your code and see what the problem is.

Comment: Would be helpful to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just ran what you have and found zero problems. Your problem may come from something else in the code.

Comment: I was looking through `PrintWriter` and found "will encode characters using the default charset", but that wouldn't be the case of it working from a .class file.  It also seems the output is printing a mix between an ArrayList (names) and an exception

Comment: @phflack If I run it as a class and compile it using the terminal (mac), it works, but if I export is as a jar, it does not. Here is my MCVE: https://hastebin.com/uqoqacaneb.swift

Comment: Using `javac MCVE.java && java MCVE`, with input "duck" and "5", input.txt had `'duck,5'`, using `javac MCVE.java && jar cfe MCVE.jar MCVE MCVE.class && java -jar MCVE.jar`, with input "cow" and "10", input.txt had `'cow,10'` - it works for me

Comment: @phflack MCVE.jar works now aswell, closing all java threads in the task manager and restarting the computer, main.jar does not, but I could delimit the problem and I'm confident that I'll eliminate the mistake. I will now always try to build a MCVE first and investigate further before asking questions here. Thank you very much for your help and patience. :)